# How to get unique value of a column in pyspark dataframe without hardcoding the column name?

Tags: list, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to extract all the unique value of a column same like pandas without hardcoding the column name. Could you please help how to do this?

Example:

```
p_k = 'Projectnum'
```

if I give like this:

```
uni_val = [x.Projectnum for x in spark_df.select('Projectnum').distinct().collect()]
uni_val = ['SR0480-000']
```

but I don't want to hardcode the column_name. So I kept the column_name in a variable p_k. But how to pas in the list?

```
uni_val = [x.pk for x in spark_df.select(pk).distinct().collect()]
```

This is giving me error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `x[0]`, not `x.p_k` because `collect` returns row objects which can be access using `[0]` but not `.p_k`

```
uni_val = [x[0] for x in spark_df.select(p_k).distinct().collect()]
```